# JavaScript reg ex apostrophe is new word boundry

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I'm trying to target the first letter of each word in a string. I'm working in JavaScript. I've found discussions for Python and PHP that don't address my problem specific to JavaScript.

```
str = "i'm a little tea pot"

regEx = /^.|\b[a-z]/g
```

I have a function that uppercases each letter the regEx finds. My result is the `m` after the apostrophe is capitalized. How do I avoid this?

After uppercase function:
I'M A Little Tea Pot"

Answer (score 1):

Capitalize first letter of every word?

```js
var string = prompt("Enter a string");

function capitalizeFirstWord(str) {
    return str.split(/\s+/).map(function(word) {
        return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }).join(' ');
}

document.getElementById("capitalized").innerHTML =  capitalizeFirstWord(string);
```

```html
<p id="capitalized"></p>
```

You split a string at a word boundary. As a parameter you pass in either an empty string or the whitespace character `\s`. This creates an array of all words in the sentence.

To get the first character, you can use `word[0]` or `word.charAt(0)`. You then perform string concatenation with the rest of the string.

This gives you an entirely new array, which needs to be converted back to a string. Call the join method on this new array

Answer (score 1):

You may  use call-back function in `str.replace`.

```js
var str = "i'm a little tea pot"
alert(str.replace(/(^|\s)([a-z])/g, function(match, group_1, group_2){return group_1 + group_2.toUpperCase()}))
```

And also if you want to convert the chars following the first char to lowercase then try this.

```
str.replace(/(^|\s)([a-z])(\S*)/g, function(x,y, z, a){return y + z.toUpperCase() + a.toLowerCase()})
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. However I'm personally not a fan of using variable names like x, y and z. I would use something more descriptive. I also don't think the function should be created as the second parameter. However the logic behind it looks good